# Missing Terminating "" character & Unexpexted @ in the program

Tags: iphone, objective-c

While writing the following code i got two errors :

1.Missing Terminating "" character
2.Unexpexted @ in the program "

Here after entering "HEllO" , "WORLD" is wriiten on the next line (i.e. after HELLO enter is pressed ).

```
    NSString *str = @"HELLO          --------> line 1
                      WORLD";        --------> line 2
```

Does anyone knows solution to this error.

Comment: If I remember correctly, strings can't be separated using line breaks... Try removing it so it's NSString *str = @"HELLO WORLD";.

Answer (score 2):

If you write string literal in several lines then each line must start and end with `"`:

```
NSString *str = @"HELLO"          --------> line 1
                  "WORLD";        --------> line 2
```

If you just want to display your text in several lines do what @jrturton suggests - add new line character (`'\n'`) to your string

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead:

```
NSString *str= @"HELLO\nWORLD";
```