# Special Characters NSString

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsstring, applescript

I have a NSString I am trying to declare so I can use it as an applescript. here is the code:

```
 NSString *script1 = @"do shell script /usr/bin/php -r ($mac = \"g1:ag:g3:cg:gg:eg\"; $porttemp = \"9\"; $ip = \"255.255.255.255\"; 
 $mac_bytes = explode(\":\", $mac); 
                     $mac_addr = \"\"; 
                     for ($i=0; $i<6; $i++) 
                     $mac_addr .= chr(hexdec($mac_bytes[$i])); 
                     $packet = \"\"; 
                     for ($i=0; $i<6; $i++) /*6x 0xFF*/ 
                     $packet .= chr(255); 
                     for ($i=0; $i<16; $i++)    /*16x MAC address*/ 
                     $packet .= $mac_addr; 
                     $port = $porttemp; 
                     $sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP); 
                     socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, TRUE); 
                     socket_sendto($sock, $packet, strlen($packet), 0, $ip, $port); 
                     socket_close($sock); 
                     );"
```

The Problem I am facing it that xcode says I am not terminating it and gives a whole bunch of errors. Any idea how I can solve it or have I got anything wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missing Terminating "" character & Unexpexted @ in the program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579781/missing-terminating-character-unexpexted-in-the-program)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must surrond every row with "".

Like:

```
NSString *HelloWorld = @"Hello"
                    " World";
```

What you are doing is:

```
NSString *HelloWorld = @"Hello
                     World";
```

which is not valid.

[Edited to correct code display, so example makes sense as line breaks were being removed.]